# Python, generate sounds of nodes using pitch, duration, and instrument?

Tags: python, audio-player

I want to generate sounds of nodes using python, just based on pitches, duration, and instruments (guitar, piano, etc.) I did this once in Java and I wish I could find a simple library in python to do it, but I haven't (I read most documentations of music libraries). Suggestions?

Comment: Such questions are off topic for Stack Overflow but you can refer to https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

Comment: Thank you @Selcuk I know this is a bit off topic but I've been playing with many of those libraries already. I'm hoping I may find someone who did something like this in the past and can point me in the right direction